# How to stretch full screen slider

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am trying to build a website using ASP.NET MVC Core 1.1.2. I would like the full screen slider on my homepage to look stretched both on Computer browsers and mobile ones but it looks like this in the browser (with a gap underneath): (http://www.tutuncarsisi.com/):

[image: On Mobile]

Here is the part of the code:

```
<div class="fullscreenbanner-container">
                <div class="fullscreenbanner">
                    <ul>
                        <li data-transition="parallaxvertical" data-slotamount="5" data-masterspeed="1000" data-title="Slide 1">
                            <img src="~/img/index/slider/slider05.jpg" alt="slidebg1" data-bgfit="contain" data-bgposition="top left" data-bgrepeat="no-repeat">
                            <div class="slider-caption container">
                                <div class="tp-caption rs-caption-1 sft start"
                                     data-hoffset="0"
                                     data-y="270"
                                     data-speed="800"
                                     data-start="1000"
                                     data-easing="Back.easeInOut"
                                     data-endspeed="300">
                                    AMSTERDAM
                                    <span></span>
                                </div>
```

Comment: `text-align: justify; display: inline-block`

Comment: Where exactly should I include this? I have 5 different slider under div class ="fullscreenbanner"

Answer (score 0):

try changing `data-bgfit="contain"` to `data-bgfit="cover"`.

Comment: that didn't work. There is always a space between the image and the div